Can't connect to my ssh server. [Permission denied (publickey).]
To be short, i've set up ubuntu server on my pc and want to connect to it trough ssh. I've generated keys and put my .pub key to ~/.ssh/ and added it to authorized_keys file. My pc is windows. The key is located in C://users/user/.ssh/ and location where the cmd is open. every time i try to connect to my server it shows a message Permission denied (publickey). Server status says sever is active (ssh.service and preset are enabled) and spams message "Connection closed by authenticating user USERNAME IP_OF_USER port PORT [preauth]". I'm pretty new to ssh, but what exactly did i do wrong?
